# Как отключить обработку нажатия Alt+Enter браузером?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html

Как сделать, чтобы браузер (IE9) не реагировал на нажатие Alt+Enter пользователем? При нажатии этих клавиш браузер делается во весь экран.

Comment: Страшно интересно - зачем вам это?

Comment: У меня закреплено действие за Alt+Enter, а сейчас начал делать поддержку IE и выяснялось :)

Comment: Честно говоря не уверен, что это вообще возможно, особенно учитывая то что речь о так горяче всеми любимом IE :D

Comment: Должен быть какой-то workaround...

Comment: вместо того чтобы переписать код страдать, ИМХО полнейшей дуристикой, опять таки ИМХО неправильно :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда-то задавался этим вопросом. В результате пришлось отказаться от использования `Alt+Enter`. Позже я нашел один-единственный вариант, который похож на правду (остальные были совершенно нелепые и неработающие), на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592847/how-can-i-disable-alt-enter-in-ie): программно генерировать событие `F11` (то же самое, что и `Alt+Enter`) с задержкой 100 мс. Получится, что браузеру сначала придет событие на переход в полноэкранный режим, а потом - на возврат в обычный режим. Но за достоверность этого метода не ручаюсь.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.onkeydown = handleHotKeys;

function handleHotKeys(e) {
    var keynum = getKeyCode(e);
    var e = e || window.event;
    if (keynum==13 && e.altKey) { // handle enter+alt
        setTimeout("toggleFullscreenMode",100);
    }

}
function getKeyCode(e){
    if (!e)  { // IE
        e=window.event;
        return e.keyCode;
    } else { // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        return e.which;
    }
}

function toggleFullscreenMode() {
  var obj = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell");
  obj.SendKeys("{F11}");
}
</script>
```